# C++ warning [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c++, class, constructor

i have a problem with my c++ code, there is no errors but only warning which is preventing my code to work as it should. I would like to multiply screen size by percentage and than print it.

this is in my .h file:

```
SmartWatch* multiply(SmartWatch* second, double percentage);
```

And this is in my .cpp file:

```
SmartWatch* SmartWatch::multiply(SmartWatch* second, double percentage){
    second->getScreen_size() * percentage;
    return second;
}
```

and this is in main:

```
SmartWatch *multiplied = &watch[0];
multiplied = multiplied ->multiply(&watch[1], 0.23);
multiplied->print();
```

i get this warning:

smartwatch.cpp:69:31: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
second->getScreen_size() * percentage;

I am new at this, so i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: _" preventing my code to work as it should"_ - So what behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you observing? Unless we know exactly what the problem is how do you expect us to tell you how to fix it?

Comment: `second->getScreen_size() * percentage;`  So you multiplied two numbers.  What are you doing with the result of the multiplication?  Right now, the result disappears into thin air after that line is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually store the value of the multiplication in the `multiply` method anywhere. The compiler is warning you because the line of code `second->getScreen_size() * percentage;` doesn't store a result or change a value. The result of the multiplication will be discarded.

To fix the warning, you should store the result back into the `SmartWatch* second` pointer somewhere. I'm not sure what your class design looks like, but you could do something like:

```
second->setScreen_size(second->getScreen_size() * percentage);
```

to remove the warning and then actually accomplish something with the method you've written.

Answer (score 3):

You are computing the product of `second->getScreen_size()` and `percentage`.

The compiler is telling you that the result is not being used.

Computing a product is only useful if you do something with the result, like storing it in a variable. If you do not do anything with it, the compiler will just remove it to improve the speed of your program.

Since you programmed something that will never, ever, be actually done, your compiler is telling you that you may have made a mistake there. Since this is not a technical error, this is only considered a *warning* by the compiler.